# Inno Setup : {code: ...} not working for OutputBaseFilename?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to programmatically set the name of the output file **using pascal code**. The following code is written in section `[Setup]` and the function `MyFileName` is placed in section `[Code]`.

```
OutputBaseFilename={code:MyFileName}
```

But it creates a file of 0 kb named `{code`. Strangely, this kind of call works for `AppVersion`...

Does someone knows a workaroud ?

PS : See [Scripted constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use [`{code:...}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) scripting constant for the [`OutputBaseFilename`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_outputbasefilename) directive because this directive specifies the name for the resulting setup file and thus has to be known at compilation time.

Comment: Damn. So how can I proceed ?

Comment: Well, the only way is to utilize preprocessor, but I don't know what were you going to execute in your `MyFileName` function. If you describe it, I can try to translate it to preprocessor code (if possible).

Comment: I did would avoid use ISPP x) Basically it formats the file version. Ex : `1.9.3.165` => `1.09.3` (keeps the 3 first values and the second is on two digits)

Comment: Well, actually I've been lying in my comment. Preprocessor is not the only option. If you are using one of the Inno Setup IDEs, it might have implemented post build events, where you can run some script which would rename the output binary file for you. But I would like to investigate what's wrong with the built-in preprocessor because that sounds like a bug. Could you show the code that you used to get your file version ? Was that just [`GetFileVersion`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getfileversion) ? Are you sure the version string your application has isn't just that ?

Comment: I've putted it in my first message. Thanks

Comment: That extra 0 is there because of `%.2d` used in the format of your `Format` function call. But I would rather discard that code. It's too much fixed to the given input. Still I'm missing one thing here; what is in the `PRODUCT_VERSION_FULL` defined variable ? Preprocessor has built-in function to get version string from any file that you point to, so it looks to me pointless to parse this version from a concatenated string. I would rather declare a variable for version where I would get the version from a file and concatenate it to the full version string.

Comment: Something [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/jQ3rdM7S). It gets the version from the `MyProgram.exe` binary file and stores it to the `PRODUCT_VERSION` defined variable. This gives you two variables. One with the actual version obtained from the file (`PRODUCT_VERSION`) and the second one with the name and version (`PRODUCT_VERSION_FULL`). You can use then both. I've shown there how to specify the name of the output file as `Setup for version` followed by the determined file version.

Comment: ISPP doesn't do any formatting of the version numbers. you can string the four components together in whatever format you want though.

Comment: @TLama Sorry I forgot to tell you : `#define PRODUCT_VERSION_FULL GetFileVersion("Program.exe")`
@Deanna Yes it does. Windows or ISPP makes a "integer" formatting...
But i've found an alternative solution to my real problem, **I will read "ProductVersion" (no formatting) instead of "FileVersion"** `#define PRODUCT_VERSION_FULL GetStringFileInfo("Program.exe", "ProductVersion")` Thanks a lots !

Comment: That's strange. The current version of ISPP's `GetFileVersion` does no integer formatting you described. The [`value it returns`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/ISPP/IsppFuncs.pas#L820) are just dot delimited integers of the file version (without 0 padding or any other extra formatting).

Comment: @56ka Sorry, `GetFileVersion` gives you the dotted quad version number. `ParseVersion` gives you the individual components you can can combine and format as you wish.

Comment: @Deanna, it still doesn't explain why would variable defined to read version string with `GetFileVersion` do any formatting. From the code (of the current version) I've linked in my previous comment I'm sure it doesn't. The `IntToStr` function converts an integer to a non-padded numeric string. And the rest is concatenation of those numeric strings using dot delimiter.

Comment: @TLama Presumably as the `VERSION` and PE resource internal format is a high and low 32-bit value, it splits it into the more familier dotted quad format.

Comment: I've made some tests and apparently `GetFileVersion` asks to Windows and Windows makes a formatting. If you use `GetStringFileInfo("Program.exe", "FileVersion")` the version is given without formatting.

Comment: @Deanna, 56ka, there is really no 0 padding. My confusion is from the fact that `GetFileVersion` function can never return 0 padded number portion. Look at [`how the final version string is build`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/ISPP/IsppFuncs.pas#L823) inside. The `IntToStr` conversion function called there for each version number portion will never return a 0 padded string. If the version portion would be stored like `09`, the `IntToStr` would convert it to `9`. So, the version like `1.9.3.165` can never be returned as `1.09.3`.

Comment: @TLama I never said it was zero padded, That's why I said the components could be joined however they wished as a string. I'm confused as to what the actual problem is now.

Comment: @Deanna, sorry, my confusion. I'm still talking about [`this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508764/inno-setup-code-not-working-for-outputbasefilename/22508802?noredirect=1#comment34246634_22508802) which describes something that can never happen with the current preprocessor's `GetFileVersion` function.